# What is this line for and what does it do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails and I wanna know more about this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

Answer (score 4):

This is [strong parameter](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) in Ruby on rails.

This makes Action Controller parameters forbidden to be used in Active Model mass assignment until they have been explicitly enumerated.

For example if send location attribute in the request and if you don't permit `location` parameter in the require, `location` parameter will be forbidden and `params` will forbid this attribute.

Like following request in json

```
{
   "user": {
          "name" : "johnny dep",
          "location" : "hollywood"
   }
}
```

with following code in controller

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name)
```

Now this will forbid location attribute. In simple it safeguard your rails code from scary internet world where attackers may try to send extra attributes to rails server.

Another example if your request in json looks like the following

```
{
    "user": {
        "name": "johnny dep",
        "email": "johnny@gmail.com",
        "qualification": {
            "name": "bachelor in arts",
            "college": "trinity"
        }
    }
}
```

Your controller can allow additional parameters for qualification using the following code

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, qualification: [:name, :college])
```

Comment: Thank you! Its so helpful and interesting for me :)

Comment: Glad it helped. You can accept the answer if it works for you